# How to resolve Tensorflow Fetch argument error while trying to pass arguments through feed_dict?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Below is the code that I am running where in I am implementing a paper. I take two matrices, multiply them and then perform clustering. What am I doing wrong?

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10,10)
b = np.random.rand(10,5)
F = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10], name='F')
mask = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 5], name='mask')

def getZfeature(F,mask):
    return tf.matmul(F,mask)

def cluster(zfeature):    
    #km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
    #km.fit(x)
    #mu = km.cluster_centers_
    return zfeature

def computeQ(zfeature,mu):
    print "computing q matrix"
    print type(zfeature), type(mu)

#construct model
zfeature = getZfeature(F,mask)
mu = cluster(zfeature)
q = computeQ(zfeature,mu)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    sess.run(q, feed_dict={F: a, mask: b})
```

Comment: An error message would make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: You may not be aware that you can choose an answer if one has helped you, I noticed that you have asked a few questions in the past but haven't selected any answers yet.

Answer (score 1):

Working code below. Your problem is that `q` and `mu` don't do anything. `q` is a reference to the function `computeQ` as it doesn't return anything. `mu` doesn't do anything so in this answer I have evaluated `zfeature`. You can do more tensor operations in these two functions but you need to return a tensor for it to work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10,10)
b = np.random.rand(10,5)
F = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10], name='F')
mask = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 5], name='mask')

def getZfeature(F,mask):
    return tf.matmul(F,mask)

def cluster(zfeature):
    #km = KMeans(n_clusters=3)
    #km.fit(x)
    #mu = km.cluster_centers_
    return zfeature

def computeQ(zfeature,mu):
    print ("computing q matrix")
    print (type(zfeature), type(mu))

#construct model
zfeature = getZfeature(F,mask)
mu = cluster(zfeature)
q = computeQ(zfeature,mu)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    result=sess.run(zfeature, feed_dict={F: a, mask: b})
    print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Its working. I do not know how I missed the return statement. 
I do have one more query though. What is the best way to perform clustering on zfeature in the above code, which is a tensor ops. I get this error ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence when I pass zfeature to kmeans.

Comment: That is a pretty big question. Using your code you would need to query the graph then apply kmeans and the clustering sklearn ops. If youa re not fully committed to your layout then this website has a good example of clustering with TF.  I created a new answer for completeness. https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/11/14/k-means-clustering-with-tensorflow/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for k-means clustering using tensorflow from https://codesachin.wordpress.com/2015/11/14/k-means-clustering-with-tensorflow/

```
import tensorflow as tf
from random import choice, shuffle
from numpy import array


def TFKMeansCluster(vectors, noofclusters):
    """
    K-Means Clustering using TensorFlow.
    'vectors' should be a n*k 2-D NumPy array, where n is the number
    of vectors of dimensionality k.
    'noofclusters' should be an integer.
    """

    noofclusters = int(noofclusters)
    assert noofclusters < len(vectors)

    #Find out the dimensionality
    dim = len(vectors[0])

    #Will help select random centroids from among the available vectors
    vector_indices = list(range(len(vectors)))
    shuffle(vector_indices)

    #GRAPH OF COMPUTATION
    #We initialize a new graph and set it as the default during each run
    #of this algorithm. This ensures that as this function is called
    #multiple times, the default graph doesn't keep getting crowded with
    #unused ops and Variables from previous function calls.

    graph = tf.Graph()

    with graph.as_default():

        #SESSION OF COMPUTATION

        sess = tf.Session()

        ##CONSTRUCTING THE ELEMENTS OF COMPUTATION

        ##First lets ensure we have a Variable vector for each centroid,
        ##initialized to one of the vectors from the available data points
        centroids = [tf.Variable((vectors[vector_indices[i]]))
                     for i in range(noofclusters)]
        ##These nodes will assign the centroid Variables the appropriate
        ##values
        centroid_value = tf.placeholder("float64", [dim])
        cent_assigns = []
        for centroid in centroids:
            cent_assigns.append(tf.assign(centroid, centroid_value))

        ##Variables for cluster assignments of individual vectors(initialized
        ##to 0 at first)
        assignments = [tf.Variable(0) for i in range(len(vectors))]
        ##These nodes will assign an assignment Variable the appropriate
        ##value
        assignment_value = tf.placeholder("int32")
        cluster_assigns = []
        for assignment in assignments:
            cluster_assigns.append(tf.assign(assignment,
                                             assignment_value))

        ##Now lets construct the node that will compute the mean
        #The placeholder for the input
        mean_input = tf.placeholder("float", [None, dim])
        #The Node/op takes the input and computes a mean along the 0th
        #dimension, i.e. the list of input vectors
        mean_op = tf.reduce_mean(mean_input, 0)

        ##Node for computing Euclidean distances
        #Placeholders for input
        v1 = tf.placeholder("float", [dim])
        v2 = tf.placeholder("float", [dim])
        euclid_dist = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(tf.sub(
            v1, v2), 2)))

        ##This node will figure out which cluster to assign a vector to,
        ##based on Euclidean distances of the vector from the centroids.
        #Placeholder for input
        centroid_distances = tf.placeholder("float", [noofclusters])
        cluster_assignment = tf.argmin(centroid_distances, 0)

        ##INITIALIZING STATE VARIABLES

        ##This will help initialization of all Variables defined with respect
        ##to the graph. The Variable-initializer should be defined after
        ##all the Variables have been constructed, so that each of them
        ##will be included in the initialization.
        init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        #Initialize all variables
        sess.run(init_op)

        ##CLUSTERING ITERATIONS

        #Now perform the Expectation-Maximization steps of K-Means clustering
        #iterations. To keep things simple, we will only do a set number of
        #iterations, instead of using a Stopping Criterion.
        noofiterations = 100
        for iteration_n in range(noofiterations):

            ##EXPECTATION STEP
            ##Based on the centroid locations till last iteration, compute
            ##the _expected_ centroid assignments.
            #Iterate over each vector
            for vector_n in range(len(vectors)):
                vect = vectors[vector_n]
                #Compute Euclidean distance between this vector and each
                #centroid. Remember that this list cannot be named
                #'centroid_distances', since that is the input to the
                #cluster assignment node.
                distances = [sess.run(euclid_dist, feed_dict={
                    v1: vect, v2: sess.run(centroid)})
                             for centroid in centroids]
                #Now use the cluster assignment node, with the distances
                #as the input
                assignment = sess.run(cluster_assignment, feed_dict = {
                    centroid_distances: distances})
                #Now assign the value to the appropriate state variable
                sess.run(cluster_assigns[vector_n], feed_dict={
                    assignment_value: assignment})

            ##MAXIMIZATION STEP
            #Based on the expected state computed from the Expectation Step,
            #compute the locations of the centroids so as to maximize the
            #overall objective of minimizing within-cluster Sum-of-Squares
            for cluster_n in range(noofclusters):
                #Collect all the vectors assigned to this cluster
                assigned_vects = [vectors[i] for i in range(len(vectors))
                                  if sess.run(assignments[i]) == cluster_n]
                #Compute new centroid location
                new_location = sess.run(mean_op, feed_dict={
                    mean_input: array(assigned_vects)})
                #Assign value to appropriate variable
                sess.run(cent_assigns[cluster_n], feed_dict={
                    centroid_value: new_location})

        #Return centroids and assignments
        centroids = sess.run(centroids)
        assignments = sess.run(assignments)
        return centroids, assignments
```